# Subprocess.call ffmpeg making empty file

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to convert video from one format to other.

```
extension = '.avi'
extension_less_url = '../uploads/video'
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', extension_less_url + extension, extension_less_url + '.mp4'])
```

But above produces an **empty file** named 'video.mp4'.
How to correct?
This is the error I am getting:

```
The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

Comment: Your file path might not be correctly specified. Make sure you are providing absolute path for the file to be converted!

Comment: `The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.` - I get this error everytime has this to do something with it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I assume you are missing `ffmpeg` parameter, reread the `ffmpeg` documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('ffmpeg -f vfwcap -t 10 -r 25 -i 0 c:/test/sample11.avi')
```

python have a subprocess module which helps for running exec command.

In case if you want to run multiple cmd or shell commands one after another you can use the following :

```
subprocess.check_call("cd /home/pi/images; ls", shell=True)
```

here : "cd /home/pi/images" is one command which is separated using ";" to run another command "ls"

Answer (score 2):

This problem is for '.mp4'. try something else like '.mkv' for the target format of your video.
I've done this and the problem is solved